# Which design pattern is more suitable (for BDD JBehave)

Tags: design-patterns, service, automated-tests, bdd, jbehave

My automation test is currenly at UI level using JBehave and Selenium web driver. I want to extend it to test at service level. The strategy is to use BDD as a common testing language.
Instead of rushing to write the service level testing I want to carefully design the base architecture so that it would later be easy to extend further. i.e. initially testing for only one SOAP service but at later stage for several SOAP services and RESTful services as well.

Provided having a common interface to connect to service (SOAP, RESTful) Which design pattern is suitable to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for a pattern:

I would not test the service on SOAP or RESTful level at all but write the tests against a simple java class that implements all servicefunctionalitiy without any soap/rest-overhead

The pattern: ( this is special usage of the [Proxy_pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) )

- create a java interface whith all you necessary service-functionality
- implemente this interface in a java-class
- inherit your soap/rest-service from the same interface
- implement soap/rest-service by delegating all soap/rest calls to the service
  class

this approach is much simpler/faster to test because you donot need to run a server to test it.

if you web application is coded against the service interface instead against soap/rest your code is more felexible. you can decide later if your webapp should run against a soap/rest service or use the class directly.